# How did Hitler view his botched career as a painter?

Tags: nazi-germany, art, hitler, painting

It's well known that Hitler wanted to be a painter. But his painting were pretty drab and it is said that he lacked the talent.

My question is how did he view his botched career as an artist in the years 1924-1945? Did he admit that painting wasn't his strong suite or was it more like he thought he was an amazing painter but even better Chancellor? Did German art critics dare to say what they thought about the paintings?

Comment: Related: [What year was Hitler's final known painting created?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40832/what-year-was-hitlers-final-known-painting-created). You may find the sources in my answer useful for further research.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 'Hitler questions' are required strictly as per policy to show some research and all assertions like "it is said" require references.

Comment: I cannot support re-open without evidence of prior research, and clarification of existing issues (e.g. "it is said").